# export data to an excel file using PHPExcel but got error

Tags: export, phpexcel, abstract

I m learning to export data excel from database in phpexcel

i got a error **'Cannot redeclare class PHPExcel_Writer_Abstract'**

I have included the following libraries...
include 'PHPExcel.php';

include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

include 'PHPExcel\Writer\Abstract.php';

stills doesn't work out. error is. 'Cannot redeclare class PHPExcel_Writer_Abstract'

Comment: It might be the case, that you only have to include PHPExcel, since it will include Writer\Abstract. If you are going to include it again, you will get the error you actually have. Give it a shot :)

Comment: Why are you trying to include `PHPExcel\Writer\Abstract.php`.... PHPExcel has an autoloader, you should just include `PHPExcel.php` and then let the autoloader handle all the other includes that you need